# Unable to publish from develop branch after linked service deletion in other branch

Tags: azure-synapse

I worked on a "test" branch based on develop branch where publish is authorized.
On test branch I deleted some linked services that I don't need anymore.
I did a pull request and merged my branch on develop.

When I try to publish from develop in Synapse I have the following error I don't know how to solve:

```
Detailed publish errors
Invalid references or dependencies found. This is likely due to publishing outside of Git mode or editing and deleting linked services in other branches. To recover from this state, please refer to the errors below and our Git troubleshooting guide

Errors
Error
The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference 'raw_data_format'. Please ensure 'raw_data_format' exists in data factory mode and recreate it in Git mode if already present.
```

How can I solve the publish problem ? I did revert commits concerning my linked service deletion on the test branch and did pull request on develop branch. I see all linked services on develop branch but still same errors when trying to publish.

raw_data_format is a pipeline that I see on Synapse UI and in TemplateForWorkspace.json in the publish branch.

Comment: The message says "recreate it in Git mode" - did you try that? In other words, add it back and Publish. Once successful, you should be able to delete it properly IF there are no existing references.

Comment: I don't know what I have to recreate. Pipeline  was always there, I didn't deleted it. Linked services ? Only thing I deleted is linked services. But I did revert on git in azure devops

Comment: To be more specific, I have everything working well in old synapse. Migration has been done to have a new synapse in other resource group. So everything comes from git devops

Comment: Try recreating the Linked Service. Make sure to use the same name as before. Then get everything committed, merged, and published. Then create a new branch and try to delete the Linked Service, then commit, merge, and publish.